Anime, probably from the 80s~90s, with a girl using a scooter-like vehicle on water
I don't have any images or clips unfortunately but a few things about this anime:
There was a scene with a girl using a scooter-like vehicle on water after she and her grandfather (?) and brother had an argument and she went of to the sea. She then enters the water with this vehicle and drops it and her hair changes color and stuff, I think because she's not human. 
I've been looking for this for years but it's not very searchable.

Is it an anime TV show or film?

@catija i can't recall :( i was too young to remember but it was probably a film since I never saw any episodes or anything on that channel again.

I found it!!
https://m.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/3901tx/tomtmovie_pre1990s_french_anime_movie_about_a/
It's "Coral Reef Legend: Elfie of the Blue Sea". 
